# MAAS Network Topology

Tags: networking, maas

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/10/maas-network-layouts-for-the-landscape-autopilot/

The above page refers to, "In both of these models, at least one node needs to have two network interfaces connected to networks that MAAS knows about"

Is this a requirement?
if yes,
Is it a MAAS requirement or only when AutoPilot is used?

What is the reason behind the use of a multi-homed host in this topology?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a requirement when deploying OpenStack. The neutron gateway machine requires two interfaces. One interface for communication to the other OpenStack services and another interface to route traffic from the virtual machines in/out of the overlay network.

MAAS only requires that a machine have one interface where it can PXE boot from a rack controller.